# Returning Value When Object Property Doesn't Exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Running a test on my code. It should return 0 if the property passed into the function does not exist. But its not returning anything. Did I make a typo?

```
var obj = {
  key: [1, 2, 3]
};

function getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key].length === 0 || Array.isArray(obj[key]) === false || obj.hasOwnProperty(key) === false) {
    return 0;
  }
  var average = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
    average += obj[key][i];
  }
  average /= obj[key].length;
  return average;
}

console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, 'notKey'));
```

Comment: Perhaps you should trap for run-time errors in your  function (at least temporarily).  Would a division by zero error ever be possible even with a matching key?  (Also, not crazy about the === in condition statements).

Comment: the check is in the opposite order .. `hasOwnProperty` should be first, then  `isArray` and length

Answer (score 3):

If you don't pass an array to your function, it fails when it tries to get the `length` of the object that was passed, so that shouldn't be how you test initially. You just need to see if the property exists and that is done by simply attempting to access the property in an `if` condition.

Now, if you are going to add tests to see if the property does exist and that it is an array, then you have to add more tests to check the items in the array to see if they are numbers, otherwise trying to get a numerical average will fail.

Since there are really two things to do (check if the property is there and get math average), I would break this into two functions:

```js
var obj1 = {
  key: [1, 2, 3]
};

var obj2 = {
  key: [1, "test", 3]
};

function getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key] && Array.isArray(obj[key])) { 
    // Ok, we have the right property and there is an array there,
    // now we have to test that each item in the array is a number
    var numbers = obj[key].every(function (currentValue) {
      return typeof currentValue === "number";
    });
    
    // Return the average if we have all numbers or 0 if not
    return numbers ? getAverage(obj[key]) : 0;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function getAverage(arr){
  var average = 0;
  // Array.forEach() is much simpler than counting loops
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    average += item;
  });
  return average / arr.length;
}

console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj1, 'notkey'));  // 0
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj1, 'key'));     // 2
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj2, 'key'));     // 0 - obj2 does not contain all numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `obj['notKey']` does not exist, it does not return an array. Therefore you cannot do `.length` of undefined. I would change it to `typeof` to see if its defined or not.

```
var obj = {
  key: [1, 2, 3]
};

function getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {

  if (typeof obj[key] == 'undefined' || Array.isArray(obj[key]) === false || obj.hasOwnProperty(key) === false) {
    return 0;
  }

  var average = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
    average += obj[key][i];
  }
  average /= obj[key].length;
  return average;
}

console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, 'notKey'));
```